# Restart service when memory is used over 90%

Tags: debian, bash

I am not sure if it is even possible, but can I somehow restart service when memory has been already used over 90%?

I mean script will check memory, and if memory has been used over 90% it will restart/execute restart of my service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote own script in the end

```
m=`free -m | head -n value | tail -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f value`
if [ $m -ge 10000 ]; then
  systemctl restart service
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at SystemD's [resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

Combining `MemoryMax` and `Restart=always` should do the trick.

Comment: I was looking more for something like "if memory usage is over 90% restart this service" I dont know how to parse memory usage in percentege and use it as variable.

Comment: Um... calculate it with bc? If you use puppet or ansible you can do it with a template + fact.

Comment: The problem with that is that it uses the oom killer, so it doesn't do a clean shutdown. What I want is, if the process exceeds a certain amount of memory, trigger a clean restart (that is, run the stop action, then run the start action).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, more succinct way of doing it, that could be used directly in a cron task:

```
[ $(free | awk '/Mem/{printf "%d", $3/$2 * 100.0}') -ge 90 ] && /usr/bin/systemctl restart service
```